# PAServer debugging stops working after exception

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney, paserver

When I debug an app using PAServer (21.0), no matter on which platform, if exception was raised, and I then try to continue debugging (using `Run - Run (F9)`), all debugging functionality stops working, as if I chose `Run - Detach From Program`, even if IDE stays in debugging layout

Is it only me who experience this? I tried searching https://quality.embarcadero.com , but did not find anything related, perhaps because lack of JIRA searching skills.

I saw this behavior on MacOS, Linux, and Windows. You can reproduce it using following console app:

```
program PAServerDebuggingErrorDemo;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

begin
  try
    try
      raise Exception.Create('after this exception is raised, breakpoints don''t work any more, '+
        'same for stepping, no matter assembler or source');
    except
      on E: Exception do
        Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    Readln;
  end;
end.
```

There's no need in separate machine to reproduce it - even local PAServer will act the same.

Does anyone know any workaround?
Or, at least, something more about the error?

Comment: Check your Firewall settings. Even on local Machine PAServer is communicating with Delphi through a network connection. So if your Firewall is blocking or partially blocking network traffic to either Delphi or PAServer it could cause problems during debugging session or even prevent Debugging session even starting.

Comment: @SilverWarior, looks like you were right. I didn't allow BDS to communicate on public networks when Windows fiewall first asked me, and after I found these rules and disabled them, at least debugging with local PAServer started working. Thanks.
Will try with other platforms and report here soon